# Java message not sending to server unless prior client instance is closed

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, chat

I am creating a program in which a server can receive messages from multiple clients. The clients would create the connection and upon clicking a button, sending information and then close the connection (not a back and forth live chat program).

The problem I'm having right now is that I run the server program class, then run two the client program twice (to simulate two users connecting). However when I send information on the client class created 2nd, it won't go through or be processed until after the 1st client has been closed.

This is also my first time using sockets and threads so any advice regarding what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated

I'm just calling the methods right now through static void mains

```
    new Server().runServer();

public void runServer() throws SocketException, IOException{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    System.out.println("Server up");

    while(true){
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        new ServerThread(socket).run();
    }
}

public class ServerThread extends Thread{ //
    Socket socket;
    ServerThread(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            String message = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                  Server.addToQueue(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        } finally{
            try {
                if (socket != null)
                    socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
The client code is as follows:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        sendToServer();
    }
public static void sendToServer(){
    String readerInput;
    Socket socket = null; 
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        readerInput = bufferedReader.readLine();
        printWriter.println(readerInput);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    } finally{
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have mis-stated the problem. The message is sent all right, but it isn't *received,* because of a bug in your server:

```
new ServerThread(socket).run();
```

That should be:

```
new ServerThread(socket).start();
```

At present your server isn't multi-threaded, so it can only handle one client at a time.

Comment: thanks mate :) this change worked, guess I need to look up thread more instead of following tutorials

Comment: I think it was a combination of a few random java socket live chat examples I watched on youtube. However I think they might have used implements Runnable instead of extending Thread which is why I might have gotten run confused with start ¬_¬

Comment: I would be astonished. `Runnable` vs. `Thread` makes no difference to whether you should use `start()`. Don't use YouTube when there are official tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

The call `new ServerThread(socket).run()` doesn't start a separate thread but executes the run-method in the current thread instead. That's the reason why communication with a second client is not taking place before the first client disconnects. In order to create separate threads you will have to use `start()` instead of `run()`.

Comment: thanks mate :) this change worked, guess I need to look up thread more instead of following tutorials